# Remove empty table rows output buffering?

Tags: php, buffering

I have a large static table which is generated by a cgi script from a tmp file to a php file.

If it outputs

`<td> </td>`

Can I remove these with output buffering.

Comment: Solved this myself with str_replace

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_replace, it would look something like this

```
$str = '<tables><tr><td>bla</td><td> </td></tr></table>';
$str = preg_replace('/<td>\\s+<\/td>/', '', $str);
```

But keep in mind if you delete the whole blank td you need to manage the colspawn's so i would prefere something like this

```
$str = '<tables><tr><td>bla</td><td> </td></tr></table>';
$str = preg_replace('/<td>\\s+<\/td>/', '<td></td>', $str);
```